# Accessing ng-repeat scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of items which get highlighted(using selectedData class) when the user clicks on them.

```
<div>Remove highlight </div>
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="data in inputData">
    <span title="{{data}}" ng-class="selected ? 'selectedData' :  ''" ng-click="selected = !selected;">
        {{data}} 
      </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to **remove the hightlight of all list item** (inturn remove the selectedData class) when i click on a clear button which is outside the list, in other words, reset `selected` for each `<li>`.Since ng-repeat creates its own scope, how do i accomplish this.

Comment: What do you mean by clear the filters?

Comment: It is not correct to call a click function : `ng-click="selected = !selected; ng-click="filterData()"`

Comment: i think you are trying to reset fiter on click on button , also now u are applying fiter using click on list item and setting ng-click="selected = !selected;". So you can apply same ng-click condition to button.

Comment: sorry.. typo.. updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<li id="list"... ng-repeat...>
  <span ng-class="selected: selected[$index] ? 'selectedData' : ''" ng-click="selected[$index] = !selected[$index]">

</li>

function clear() {  

  for (i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) { 
    selected[i] = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This would work. But i wanted to do it without accessing the dom.. This way,if i again click on an item. its previous "selecteed" state would still reflect.

Answer (score 0):

@Sidharth Panwar's answer is mostly correct

but I am not sure if `selected:` is needed in `<span ng-class="selected: selected[$index] ? 'selectedData' : ''"`, I manage to make it work with just the trenary operator:

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module("app",[])
.controller("controller", function($scope){
  $scope.selected=[]; // <--- this is the most important part of the solution
  $scope.clearSelector = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.selected.length; i++){
      $scope.selected[i] = false;
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.highlight{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="controller">
    <ul ng-init="temp=[1,2,3]">
      <li ng-repeat="i in temp" ng-click="selected[$index] = !selected[$index]" ng-class="selected[$index]?'highlight':''">
        toggel between black and red
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="clearSelector()">clear</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

if your concern is that `ng-repeat` has it's own scope and you can not manipulate its values from the parent scope (where "clear" button is), creating **an array in the parent scope** can help you centralize your control variables:

```
// both in child scope
selected=1;    // create a new variable if no existing variable named
               //"selected" in the current scope,
               // this happens when javascript knows how to create stuff ie:primitives
selected[0]=1; // need to know the address of "selected", if we can't
               // find it in the current scope, look it up in the parent scope
```

for more detail look at this link about [inheritance and scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#JSproto)